# How to sync a taxonomy between Drupal and a 3rd-party system?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a custom made system (non Drupal) that has a taxonomy like:

```
Element 1
   Element 1.1
   Element 1.2
   Element 1.3
Element 2
   Element 2.1
   Element 2.2
Element 3
   ...
```

And I have a Drupal site that I would like to be able to:

1. Use this taxonomy for tagging content, and
2. Add more terms that the non-Drupal system can use too.

Is there a popular way to ***sync*** a taxonomy in a Drupal system with an external system?

Comment: There can't be "popular" way to sync with system written and used only by your project.

Comment: @Molot please see my answer. Actually the Migrate module is a general purpose migration framework.

Comment: do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can import taxonomies, and even nested taxonomies, with CSV data generated from your source data. I have been done before and it works quite well with [module Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds).

As for your taxonomy system, you must generate dynamical CSV files (in fact, a PHP or a Drupal node with some custom code), which feeds the Imports you generate in Drupal and which are associated to a vocabulary. In that way you can generate taxonomies with children.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a popular way to sync a taxonomy in a Drupal system with an external system?

Actually yes the [Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) can be setup to ingest new terms from the old system.

Migrate is a general use migration framework (which happens to have a lot of boilerplate Drupal classes) can also be used to set Drupal as the Source of a migration and the external system as Destination of the system. In general only the SQL Table destination plugin will be use of for migrations TO the legacy system out of the box. If you want to create special Migration classes similar to MigrateDestinationNode but specific to your external systems data entities -- that's up to you.

So you could have 2 custom migrations you write in PHP:

- MigrateTermsFromLegacySystem - which ingests any unknown terms into Drupal.
- MigrateDrupalTermsToLegacySystem - which sends any unknown terms to your legacy systems "terms" tables.

You would run these migrations via Cron, or a Rule.

As 1 real world example I've taken a 3rd party .NET SOAP request and used Migrate to take it's XML based output and feed it into a 3rd party non-drupal mysql database. I'm simply using Migrate and Drupal as a visual, interactive frontend to develop the migration code.

Comment: +1 If the amount of vocabularies and terms are huge I think that this is the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module. The module does not synchronize terms but you can add the terms massively. See the description:

> This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A
>   vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms
>   can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.

Some of their operations and key features are:

- dynamic treeview
- mass deleting
- mass adding of new terms
- moving of terms in hierarchies
- fast weight changing with up and down arrows (and AJAX saving)
- AJAX powered term editing form
- CSV Export of terms
- Double Tree interface for moving terms in hierarchies, adding new translations and switching terms between different vocabularies

Answer (score 0):

#### Drupal 7

In Drupal 7, you can use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) with [UUID Features Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) module for easier to share and integrate content between sites. Check also [Features Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra) module.

#### Drupal 8

In Drupal 8 all core entities support UUIDs and it's advised to use core configuration management system for that, unfortunately it doesn't support syncing of Taxonomy terms. The best would be to export them into CSV format and import on hook_update.